# how to align these buttons in html uniformly

Tags: css, html, button

I have  two buttons. one button with value "a" and other button with "/". Both the buttons are of different width. How to make it uniform?

Comment: Please post code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the width with something like

```css
width: 20px;
```